# Word crashes on opening file for write access

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I own Office 2010 Pro Plus, and despite its other features I really only use Word. The problem is, recently, when I start it, it freezes and crashes. I have run through all the Microsoft fixit stuff, run Office removal tools, deleted all the registry keys and all the leftover files, cleared my temp directory, and run CCleaner. I have also tried re-installing Windows 7 and Microsoft .NET. The only thing I am refusing to do is wipe and start over.

In all my troubleshooting, I have narrowed down the problem. I can open files in protected mode. I can also open Word in safe mode, until I try to create a new file; then Word crashes. I can read files, but as soon as Word requests write access, it crashes. I have tried disabling all add-ins and deleting `Normal.dot`, but nothing has worked. I need Word for my school, but I also need my files.

Comment: does the same thing happen with the other Office components or just Microsoft Word?

Comment: This is ringing a bell -- I think I had the same problem with Excel a couple of years back.  I'm thinking that "autorecover file location" in Options ->Save got hosed up -- if not that then something similar.  Stupidly, resetting all sorts of other stuff doesn't fix it.

Comment: Did you try the OffCAT?